# Vue JS - Making my conditions in a function more efficient

Tags: javascript, performance, function, vue.js, vuejs2

I get the feeling that this function can be shortened, but I'm not sure what would be the best way to do it. I would like to make the following function more efficient. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

My Function

```
onStudentActionSelect: function () {
      if (this.selectedRows.length === 1) {
        this.$store.commit(SET_MODAL_OPTIONS, {
          modalContent: MODAL_CONTENT.DELETE_STUDENT(this.selectedRows[0].name),
          modalSettings: MODAL_SETTINGS.CANCEL_DELETE,
          modalCallback: this.deleteStudent
        })
      } else if (this.selectedRows.length > 1) {
        this.$store.commit(SET_MODAL_OPTIONS, {
          modalContent: MODAL_CONTENT.DELETE_STUDENTS(this.selectedRows.length),
          modalSettings: MODAL_SETTINGS.CANCEL_DELETE,
          modalCallback: this.deleteStudents
        })
      }
    }
```

Comment: You could use ternary expressions to turn this into a single commit call, but readability will suffer. Imo, leave it as it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing that changes is the content of your modal, so you can determine that before doing a commit to the store. Simplifying code like this usually involves determining the parts that stay the same, and preparing the rest in variables/parameters.

```js
onStudentActionSelect: function () {
  // Do nothing if we have nothing selected
  if (!this.selectedRows.length) {
    return;
  }

  const modalContent = this.selectedRows.length === 1 ? MODAL_CONTENT.DELETE_STUDENT(this.selectedRows[0].name) : MODAL_CONTENT.DELETE_STUDENTS(this.selectedRows.length);

  this.$store.commit(SET_MODAL_OPTIONS, {
    modalContent,
    modalSettings: MODAL_SETTINGS.CANCEL_DELETE,
    modalCallback: this.deleteStudent
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Move the condition to the place where there's a difference between the two condition blocks :

```
onStudentActionSelect: function () {
   let value;
   if (this.selectedRows.length === 1) {
         value=this.selectedRows[0].name
       }else if(this.selectedRows.length > 1){
          value=this.selectedRows.length
      }
        this.$store.commit(SET_MODAL_OPTIONS, {
          modalContent: MODAL_CONTENT.DELETE_STUDENT(value),
          modalSettings: MODAL_SETTINGS.CANCEL_DELETE,
          modalCallback: this.deleteStudent
        })
      
    }
```

using the ternary operator doesn't exclude the case when the length===0

Answer (score 1):

Deal with the if/else with `?` operator for shortened purpose, here is the code:

```
onStudentActionSelect: function () {
      this.$store.commit(SET_MODAL_OPTIONS, {
          modalContent: MODAL_CONTENT.DELETE_STUDENT(this.selectedRows.length === 1 ? this.selectedRows[0].name : this.selectedRows.length),
          modalSettings: MODAL_SETTINGS.CANCEL_DELETE,
          modalCallback: this.deleteStudent
        })
    }
```

Comment: You condition will set `this.selectedRows.length` even when `Array.length` is `0`. But original conditions does not. So it is bad solution.